# Downloading and opening an incomplete ISO

Tags: iso-image

How do I go about downloading and opening an ISO partially (just want a single thing at probably the beginning of the ISO)?

Is it possible?

Comment: There are many software solutions to either mount it as "drive" or open it like any other compressed file (not that an ISO is compressed). 7zip comes to mind.

Comment: Depends on the drive which is a source for this ISO. If it is CD/DVD, then the file can be extracted from partially loaded ISO when the file body is present in loaded ISO part completely (it is possible that you'd load some intermediate session for to access this file). If this ISO source is some drive then the answer depends on the filesystem of this drive, if the file body and all FS tables needed for this file accessing is present in ISO then the file can be extracted.